# Why is my code not correctly converting JSON to CSV?

Tags: java, json, csv

I want to convert this JSON to CSV:

```
{"field1": 11,"field3": 13},
{"field1": 21,"field2": 22,"field3": 23},
{"field1": 31,"field2": 32,"field3": 33,"field4": 34}
```

and to do so I am using the following code:

```
  String jsonString1 = "{\"infile\": [{\"field1\": 11,\"field3\": 13},{\"field1\": 21,\"field2\": 22,\"field3\": 23},{\"field1\": 31,\"field2\": 32,\"field3\": 33,\"field4\": 34}]}";

     try
     {   
         output = new JSONObject(jsonString1);
         String destination = "tmp/json2csv.csv";
         JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("infile");

         File file = new File(destination);
         String csv = CDL.toString(docs);
         FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {

    }
```

I expected the CSV output to be equivalent to this table:

```
field1  field2  field3  field4
11              13  
21       22     23  
31       32     33       34
```

But currently it is outputting CSV equivalent to this table:

```
field1  field2  field3  field4
13              13  
21              23  
31              33
```

Why is this code not returning the results that I expect?

Comment: Please give us the code of the CDL.toString() method/class and the JSONObject Class. Currently the code you have given us doesn't show us any actual implementation details, so answering the question is impossible.

Comment: Show us the interesting code (which is probably CDL.toString). Otherwise we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `org.json.CDL` then you want to try the overload method `String toString(JSONArray names, JSONArray ja)`:

```
try
{
    JSONObject output = new JSONObject(jsonString1);
    JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("infile");
    JSONArray names = new JSONArray("['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']");
    String header = CDL.rowToString(names);
    String csv = header + CDL.toString(names, docs);

    String destination = "tmp/json2csv.csv";
    File file = new File(destination);
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: CDL.toString() returns "null"

Comment: You may want to check the source code of your version of CDL. Most likely there are some change after 2+ years